# ionic 2 ion-datetime ISO Format issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using ion-datetime for my appointment form. While inserting it is working fine without any problem. But when I need to update the inserted appointment date form details from back end, the date value is not displaying in ion-datetime.

Below is my code:

**update.html**:

```
<ion-item class="border-bottom">
      <ion-label  class="ionselect" >Appointment Date:</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime name="appdate" displayFormat="YYYY MMM DD" [(ngModel)]="leadDetailsUpdate.appt_date"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

**update.ts**:

```
leadDetailsUpdate={
        appt_date:''
};
```

The Date format I am getting from back end as follows: 
     `appt_date: "2017-01-01"`

Below is the error message I am getting in console:

`Error parsing date: "null". Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime format: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime`

Comment: use **toISOString()** function to convert it to ISO before display it in ion date-time

Comment: let me know if it solves the issue

Answer (score 16, accepted):

convert it to ISO format before displaying

```js
var date = new Date('2017-01-01').toISOString()
console.log(date)
```

Comment: Below is as I tried and its not coming : leadDetailsUpdate={
        appt_date: 'new Date('appt_date').toISOString()'
};

Comment: @AkashM Just create a new date using appt_date and assign it to appt_date again

Comment: If I use like you said:                                                                                              var date = new Date('appt_date').toISOString();
        console.log(date);                                                                                          in console its coming as:                                                                       `2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: @AkashM Please add the code where you are assigning value to appt_date as it is giving 'null' in your case

Comment: @AkashM also I used your string and it is working fine on Ionic 2. Are you using Ionic 1 because there is no such issue on Ionic 2 as you mentioned

Comment: I am using Ionic 2, the code all I am using is in the above question. I made some changes in the back end now my Date format is coming as below from backend: `appt_date: "2017-01-01 00:00:00"`

Comment: @AkashM your error implies that your appt_date variable you are passing to datetime is `null`. Please assign your backend value to this variable properly

Comment: I am using the same subscript name appt_date in front to display which is coming from back end. In console my backend value is coming as appt_date: "2017-01-01 00:00:00"

Answer (score 4):

Even Gaurav is right, I found that if your timezone is not +0, you can have problems with that. I found somewhere this solution:

```
let tzoffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; //offset in milliseconds
this.startTime = (new Date(this.myStartTime - tzoffset)).toISOString().slice(0,-1);
```

Then in my HTML I have it like this:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="startTime" (ionChange)="changeCheckOutStartTime()" style="padding-left: 21px"></ion-datetime>
```

And in the `changeCheckOutStartTime()` method, I take the time and create a moment:

```
changeCheckOutStartTime() {
   this.myStartTime = moment(this.startTime).toDate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ISO format before displaying, like this:

```js
this.myDate = new Date('2017-01-01').toISOString()
```

Will give us a difference of hours, each browser would do something different. In my case I had a difference of 5 hours (16/12/17 02:00 would be 16/12/17 07:00).

A better way would be to use moment as ionic recomends on its documentationn (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/#advanced-datetime-validation-and-manipulation)

Example:

1. Open console at root proyect and install moment: `npm install moment --S`.
2. Import moment in component file: `import moment from 'moment';`.
3. Set value of model variable: `this.myDate = moment().format()`.

The best would be create a pipe. Well check this demo http://plnkr.co/edit/MHjUdC for inspiration, goog luck :)