# Ionic ion-datetime - default it to the date and time with the timezone of the user's device

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3. I used ion-datetime component:

```
myDate: String = new Date().toISOString();

<ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" pickerFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
```

I want to have today's date that depends on the timezone of the user device. Unfortunately **new Date().toISOString()** always returns the GMT one.
any advises how to this properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the `toLocaleString()` function of the Javascript Date Object.

```
 myDate: String = new Date().toLocaleString();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using ISO format give us a difference of hours, each browser would do something different. In my case I had a difference of 5 hours (16/12/17 02:00 would be 16/12/17 07:00).

Comment: @Daniel Eduardo Delgado Diaz the question was to get a users local date string hence I provided the solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `toLocalString()` it gives you the following format `MM/DD/YYYY, HH:MM:SS A`

If you need the a ISO 8601 format consider using the below code:

```
mydate: String = (new Date(Date.now() - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().slice(0, -1);
```

Comment: I don't know if is there any other prototype function to achieve the same result. For now this is what I am using.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open console at root proyect and install moment: `npm install moment --S`.
2. Import moment in component file: `import moment from 'moment';`.
3. Set value of model variable: `this.myDate = moment().format()`.

Check this post for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843362/7829826

Comment: Very good solution thank you @Daniel. BTW what does --s do in npm ?

Comment: Hi! It's the same than --save, it indicates to npm to save the library we are installing in package.json

Comment: Thank you xD I didn't know there was a shortcut for that